# Modify elasticsearch score based on nested field value with filter

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch version: 7.11

I have the following structure of index:

```
PUT /my-test-index
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "brand": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "id": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "availabilityId": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "priorities": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "typeId": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
            },
            "title": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For instance, using this data:

```
POST /my-test-index/_doc
{
    "id": 1,
    "brand": "Milk One",
    "availabilityId": 1,
    "title": "Great Value 2% Reduced-Fat Milk, 0.5 Gallon, 64 Fl. Oz",
    "priorities": [
        {
            "typeId": 1,
            "value": 3000
        },
        {
            "typeId": 2,
            "value": 4000
        }
    ]
}

POST /my-test-index/_doc
{
    "id": 2,
    "brand": "Milky Two",
    "availabilityId": 2,
    "title": "Great Value 3.5% Milk Fat Whole Milk, 64 Fl Oz",
    "priorities": [
        {
            "typeId": 1,
            "value": 1000
        },
        {
            "typeId": 2,
            "value": 3000
        }
    ]
}
    
POST /my-test-index/_doc
{
    "id": 3,
    "brand": "Nesty",
    "availabilityId": 3,
    "title": "Great Value 1% Low-Fat Milk, 128 Fl Oz"
}

POST /my-test-index/_doc
{
    "id": 4,
    "brand": "No milk",
    "availabilityId": 4,
    "title": "Almond Breeze Vanilla Almondmilk",
    "priorities": [
        {
            "typeId": 1,
            "value": 6000
        },
        {
            "typeId": 2,
            "value": 2000
        }
    ]
}
```

I want:

1. filtered documents by availabilityId (1, 2, 3)
2. multi match by title, brand
3. modify score by multiplying it with log1p by priorities.value, but only with type = 1. If priorities is null, then set it to 6000
4. sort by score

My query:

```
POST /my-test-index/_search?typed_keys=true
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "filter": [
                            {
                                "terms": {
                                    "availabilityId": [
                                        "1",
                                        "2",
                                        "3"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "multi_match": {
                                    "fields": [
                                        "title^100",
                                        "brand^15"
                                    ],
                                    "fuzziness": 0,
                                    "minimum_should_match": "2<80%",
                                    "query": "milk",
                                    "type": "most_fields"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "priorities",
                        "query": {
                            "function_score": {
                                "query": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "priorities.typeId": "1"
                                    }
                                },
                                "functions": [
                                    {
                                        "field_value_factor": {
                                            "field": "priorities.value",
                                            "modifier": "log1p", 
                                            "missing": 6000
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Problem:

1. final score is not multiply, but only sum
2. documents without priorities is ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the function script_score:

```
POST /my-test-index/_search?typed_keys=true
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "functions": [
                {
                  "script_score": {
                    "script" : """double priority1 = 6000; if(params._source["priorities"] != null){for (int i = 0; i < params._source["priorities"].length; ++i){ if(params._source["priorities"][i].typeId == 1) priority1 = params._source["priorities"][i].value;}} return Math.log10(priority1 + 1);"""
                  }
                }
            ],
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "filter": [
                                    {
                                        "terms": {
                                            "availabilityId": [
                                                "1",
                                                "2",
                                                "3"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [
                                    {
                                        "multi_match": {
                                            "fields": [
                                                "title^100",
                                                "brand^15"
                                            ],
                                            "fuzziness": 0,
                                            "minimum_should_match": "2<80%",
                                            "query": "milk",
                                            "type": "most_fields"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```